Umbrella Stand Screw Plug
I misplaced the screw plug for the water tank on my water-filled umbrella stand last fall. I can’t find anyone who sells replacements.  The stand is this one: link.  The opening is 1”. I don’t even know what to search for; any search I’ve done just turns up plugs for tables.

Try a 3/4" (nominal) threaded pipe plug, which is about 1" diameter and would be a likely choice if they used a standard thread size.
Alternatively an expanding rubber "test plug" of the appropriate size would probably work.
Both should be in the plumbing section of a hardware store. Ideally take the base with you so you can try it and immediately return the pipe plug if it doesn't fit, and pick up a test plug instead.

A good source is https://www.mcmaster.com/products/plugs/expansion-plugs~/

I like Mcmaster for hard to get things not stocked in stores, but the typically $15 minimum shipping charge makes going to the hardware store a lot more attractive, @fred_dot_u unless you live 50+ miles from one. They are not at all hard to get.

I haven't ordered from there for some time and didn't know they jacked up the charge that much. That turns the link into a useful reference for what to seek.

When I last ordered from them, it wasn't so much that it was jacked up as that they only offered UPS, and the first pound isn't cheap, ever, with UPS. My usual strategy is to figure out what else I should buy to spread the pain of the shipping charge around more.

Try checking out your local auto store. They have many different plugs for engine blocks, tubing, hoses, etc.

If the plug is threaded, an expanding plug may not seal well.  But it might be "good enough" for this purpose.

@Huesmann  My first reaction to this was that a plug wasn't even needed, just fill it in place, but then I thought they might want to move it and not want to lose a lot of water.

Well, that, and it'd evetually evaporate out, and I'm sure the OP wouldn't be checking the level and one day the thing might just fall over.

When the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail. My hammer isn't operational (3D printer) but this plug just screams "3D print me!"
There's a sub-reddit for requests to have custom projects designed and printed. If you don't find a suitable replacement, you would almost certainly be able to find a model designer and printer, even if it's two independent parties, to create a replacement.
If I were the designer selected, I'd suggest to lubricate the internal threads with mineral oil and press modeling clay into the perimeter of the opening. It would have to be air-dry clay, which when removed, would provide the master from which the 3D model could be measured and designed.
One could take measurements manually, of course, which allows a greater chance of error to creep in.

Would plumber’s putty work? I have some of that. The stand doesn’t move; I just don’t want the water to evaporate and the umbrella to fall on someone

My suggestion was directed at creating a suitable object for measuring and creating a 3D printed model. I'm not at all familiar with plumber's putty. Echnerwal's answer is likely going to be the most convenient, unless you like projects, as I do. I've added a link in the comments for a reliable source, or at least a good reference for your search.
